# What can interfere with library load path

Tags: c, shared-libraries

I have a C program (IDS vortex) which uses a library `libbsf`.  I have several more or less identical ubuntu machines and vortex works fine on all bar one of them.

On that one it fails to find the library.  Explicitly setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib` works.

`/usr/local/lib` is in `/etc/ld.so.conf` as well as `/etc/ld.so.conf/libc.conf`.

Running `ld.config -v` finds the library.

I am baffled as to what can be interfering and stopping this executable finding the library at run time.

I have copied the executable to one of the other machines where it finds the library.

Originally I distributed both the executable and library to all machines using puppet and when it failed on one I ended up compiling all the bits on the actual machine before deciding that it really was an issue with the library path.  Setting `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` verified that.

Suggestions solicited!!

Comment: Can you run an `strace` on the command, and see where it tries to find the library (without `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` being set)?

Comment: Also, what happens if you do `ldd <program>`?

Comment: open("/usr/lib/x86_64/libbsf.so.1.0.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("/usr/lib/x86_64", 0x7fffa13ee660) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/libbsf.so.1.0.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    stat("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=12288, ...}) = 0

i.e. searches everwhere it should except /usr/local/lib ???

Comment: When you said more or less identical machines, what are the differences?

Comment: ldd says the library is not found.

Comment: Did you run `sudo ldconfig` (just confirming - I know you mentioned it above).

Comment: @RussellFulton **NOTE:** that is `sudo ldconfig` **not** `ld.config`. It looks like your additions to `/etc/ld.so.conf` and/or `/etc/ld.so.conf/libc.conf` are not being seen (`/etc/ld.so.conf` is the proper place)

Comment: Found it!  Something must have modified the ld.so.conf stuff but not run ldconfig.   It's a loong time since I did any real C development and had not realised that simply looking at what was in the ld.so.conf file was not enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

changing anything in /etc/ld.so.conf *without* running ldconfig will cause problems.  In this case I don't know how things got out of sync but you can not assume that the current state of ld.so.conf reflects what is happening at run time.

Pointing me at strace was useful (thanks!) I started hacking ld.conf and nothing I did made any difference.  Then a colleague pointed me to ldconfig.